# TinyMCE : How to insert snippets in editor which will be replaced by plain PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I want to be able to pick in a select list inside tinyMCE a 'snippet' (for example a contact_form or poll_form) which will be placed in the editor.

example:

```
My first post is an article talking about animals
#contact_form#
```

When the row will be displayed the frontend, it'll not output `'contact_form'` **but it has to be replaced by PHP code which needs to be interpreted** `<?php include('contact_form') ?>` or something like that.

example:

```
My first post is an article talking about animals
<?php include('contact_form') ?>
// <form name="blabal">
// .....
```

Have you an idea how to achieve that please ? 
Thanks

**Edit** I won't execute the code later, the visitor will just see the form and not the php part. That's why i said that he needs to be interpreted.

How do i add a select list in TinyMCE editor in order to the admin choose which form he'll be including in the tinyMCE ?

Comment: This idea is just incredibly bad. Don't ever execute code from the outside.

Comment: I know that it's bad but i don't have the choice. The list of snippet will be array containing : the php code to execute and the snipet itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the content of an included php file using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), then simply switch this using an `str_replace()`.

```
if(strpos('#contact_form#', $input)) { // Check if we need to first
    ob_start();
    include('contact-form.php');
    $form = ob_get_contents();

    $output = str_replace('#contact_form#', $form, $input);
}
```

I hope this is what you mean, if you want to input PHP code so you can than execute it later, this would be suicide as your whole input will be executable.
Note: I haven't tested this!

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Thanks, no i won't execute it later, in the frontend they'll just see the form and not the php include or whatever php function i need to execute. I've edited my question to be more precise

Comment: ps: a str_replace isn't a little too much memory consuming if there are a lot of content in the page ?

Comment: For the custom button, check out [custom menu buttons in the TinyMCE Docs](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/custom_toolbar_button.php). `str_replace` will be a lot cheaper than using regex. How else did you think it would be possible?

Comment: I don't know, i thought that a magic option would be already in place in order to pass an array containing the snippet code and the php code to run ;-)

Comment: That's fine, I thought maybe you were thinking about explode() or something crazy :)

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: Watch out with that initial optimization check. If `$input` starts with the string "`#contact_form#`", [strpos](http://php.net/strpos#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues) will return the integer `0`, which evaluates to `false`. In that case the replacement wouldn't happen. Use `strpos() !== false`.